# Local de divulgação de material relacionado a Desenvolvimento

Tags: debate

Existe algum local no site onde é `livre` a divulgação de matérias (palestras,livros, cursos e minicursos) voltados a área de desenvolvimento e arquitetura de software, onde também os usuários poderiam fazer pedidos de indicações de matérias?

Obs: Livre de `spam` obviamente.

Comment: Acredito que o único lugar adequado para essas coisas é o [chat], mais especificamente na sala [Estouro de Pilha](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha).

Comment: Relacionado: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2403/h%C3%A1-alguma-%C3%A1rea-aqui-no-so-pt-para-pesquisas-acad%C3%AAmicas-cientificas

Comment: É triste, mas não temos um lugar apropriado para isso. Dicas de produtividade, planejamento, etc. O chat é mais um improviso. 
Vou tentar conversar com a comunidade sobre isso.